# How to prove periodicity Modulo b

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory, discrete-calculus

We have the sequence

$$
x_n=a^n \mod{b},
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. How to show that it's periodic? It is intuitively clear but I have no clue how to prove it rigorously from first principles...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Note first that periodic here means there are $K$, $P > 0$ such that $a^{i} = a^{i+P}$ for $i > K$.

One begins with showing that there are $m > n$ such that $a^{m} =  a^{n}$. Then for all $i > n$ we have
$$
a^{i} = a^{i - n + n} = a^{i - n} a^{n} = a^{i - n} a^{m} =
a^{i + (m - n)}.
$$
So you can take $K = n$ and $P = m - n$.

Answer (score -1):

Using the fact that
\begin{align}
a^{\varphi(b)}\equiv 1 \mod b
\end{align}
and the fact that for any $n$ 
\begin{align}
n = \varphi(b)k+r
\end{align}
for some $0\leq r<\varphi(b)$ we have the desired result. Here $\varphi(b)$ is the Euler Totient function.

Comment: @plus1 Even simpler, note that $a^n \mod b$ can only take a finite range of values i.e. $\{0,1,2,\dots,b-1\}$ so eventually we have$a^n=a^m \mod b$ and so $a^{n-m}=1 \mod  b$ and the sequence is periodic with a period that is a factor of $n-m$.

Comment: Thanks! But isn't there a simpler proof? I am not familiar with the Euler Totient function and it's properties..

Comment: @gandalf61 That only shows that $a^n=a^m \mod{b}$ for some m>n. Can you deduce from that that $a^{n+1}=a^{m+1} \mod{b}$ and get some kind of induction going ?

Comment: @gandalf61 Can you simply divide by $a^m$ modulo $b$? Is that one of the properties of modular arithmetic?

Comment: @gandalf61 since $m>n$, $a^{n-m}$ is not even an integer

Comment: @gandalf61, take $a = 2$ and $b = 6$. How do you go from $a^{3} \equiv a^{1} \pmod{b}$ to $a^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod{b}$?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti yes, I was too hasty. If $a$ does not have an inverse $\mod b$ then all we can conclude from the simpler argument is that the sequence is eventually periodic i.e. $a^n=a^m, a^{n+1}=a^{m+1}, a^{n+2}=a^{m+2} \dots$